# Margin: auto does not work

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Meriniuc Răzvan - Dumitru</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div id="header">
            <h3>
                Cv
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>

    </body>
</html>

.left {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 310px;
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 65px;
}

.right {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 310px;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 65px;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 720px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;

}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 65px;
    width: 720px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

h3 {
    margin: auto;
}
```

[image: With "margin:auto"]
With "margin:auto".
[image: Without "margin:auto"]
Without "margin:auto"

I am learning HTML and CSS and have tried to create a CV page, but my header won't center. I have read about this problem and the general solution seems to make the header display as a block, but it still doesn't work.
Could you please explain why this code does not center my header and offer a possible solution? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align: center;` The `h3` tag contains text.

```
h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Auto margins centre the element. They don't centre the inline content of it.

The header is centred. The text "Cv" is aligned to the left of the header.

To centre that, use `text-align`.